# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros de una fila de una tabla html con jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, tablas

Quisiera poder editar los campos de una tabla desde un listado en una página **jsp**:

```
try {
            Connection conexion=null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticketsdetrabajo", "root", "Cuatro:2cuatro");
            //creamos objeto Statement
            Statement st=conexion.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery(consultaSQL);

            while(rs.next()){
            aprobado=(int)rs.getObject("Aprobado");
            %>
                <tr>
            <td class="table2"><%=rs.getObject("NParte")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2" ><%=rs.getObject("Nempleado")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2" ><%=rs.getObject("Nombre")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2"><%=rs.getObject("Apellidos")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2"><%=rs.getObject("DescripcionTarea")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2"><%=rs.getObject("TiempoEmpleado")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2"><%=rs.getObject("FechaEntrada")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2"><%=rs.getObject("FechaEntrega")%><br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2"><% if (aprobado==1){%>Si
            <%}else {%>No<%} %>

            <br>
            </td>
            <td class="table2"><button name="btnlapiz" class="botonplano" onclick="location.href='editarpartesdetrabajo.jsp'" ><img alt="editar" src="lapiz.png"></button></td>
          </tr>
        <%}   

      }catch (java.sql.SQLException sqle){
            System.out.println("Error: " + sqle);
        }

            %>
```

Al pulsar sobre la imágen quisiera poder pasar parámetros de esa fila a un **jsp**, no sé me ocurre como hacer para que pulsando la imágen del lápiz coja esa fila y pueda pasar los parámetros otra página.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Lo más sencillo es pasar los valores por parámetro en la URL (petición GET).

   De hecho, lo más sencillo es pasar solo el ID de la fila y luego recuperar los datos desde BD.

   > onclick="location.href='editarpartesdetrabajo.jsp?NParte=<%=rs.getObject("NParte")%>'"
2. Si por cualquier razón una petición GET no es válida, creas un elemento `<form>` con un campo oculto y llamas a un método JS que actualiza el valor del campo y hace la petición:

   > onclick="enviarForm('<%=rs.getObject("NParte")%>');"

   En ambos casos, si `NParte` puede tener caracteres no alfanuméricos, puede ser necesario codificarlos (p.ej. con URL Encoder)
3. Llamas a una función javascript que recorra el DOM para obtener el valor

   > onclick="enviarTr(this);"

   Aquí, `this` es el botón; `this.parentNode` el `<td>` donde está el botón, `this.parentNode.parentNode` el `<tr>`, y del `<tr>` puedes recorrer los hijos para obtener los valores. Con eso, o bien montas la URL (como en el punto 1) o rellenas el form oculto (como en el punto 2).

Como nota adicional, en general se recomienda que hagas las peticiones a un servlet para que éste se encargue de la lógica de negocio (consultas a BD, etc.), guarde los resultados como atributos a mostrar en el *request* y usar un JSP "limpio" con JSTL. A no ser que estés tocando código antiguo que no valga la pena refactorizar, deberías considerarlo.

Comment: En el primer caso me pasa null el valor, ya que al pulsar el botón, no hay ninguna forma de saber que fila se ha elegido.
Los otros dos casos no los entiendo muy bien, pues javascript hace tiempo que dejé de practicarlo y no recuerdo prácticamente nada

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "No hay ninguna forma de saber qué fila ha elegido"? El codigo que muestras define un botón distinto por cada fila... Cada botón tendrá en su URL el parámetro indicando el elemento que corresponde a la fila.

Comment: Creo que cada botón que aparece en cada fila no se relaciona de ninguna forma con los elementos de la fila, por lo que no se puede saber que botón se ha pulsado. Se imprimen las filas y los botones al lado.

Comment: No se relaciona, por eso le metes en la URL el parámetro que indica que fila quieres modificar (el `?NParte=<%=rs.getObject("NParte")%>`). Naturalmente, al procesar la URL, sacas el parámetro del request y lo usas para buscar el elemento.

Comment: Me sigue llegando como null